# My page is in hook_admin_paths(), but doesn't show admin theme

Tags: 7

```
function mymodule_admin_paths() {
  $paths = array(
    'admin-dvr/*' => TRUE,
  );
  return $paths;
}
```

I have a module which generates a page and I want that page to be themed with the admin theme. I implemented the above hook so that when I browse to `admin-dvr/dvr/manage` it should be displaying with the admin theme.

On my dev server, this works just fine. When I push that code to production, and flush all the caches, I'll sometimes see it load with the admin theme ONCE, but then every time after that it loads with the mainsite theme.

What am I doing wrong? Why won't it load my page with the admin theme?

Comment: Seeing how the *admin-dvr/dvr/manage* has been defined in `hook_menu()` could help in giving a more detailed answer. That hook implementation isn't wrong. I can just think of a module that is changing the theme to use for that path using one of the other Drupal ways to change the theme used for a path.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you place your admin pages under `admin/dvr`. In that way you should not need to implement `hook_admin_paths()` at all.

Comment: I did, but that causes other problems which are not resolvable, which is why I wanted to know how to simply define paths outside admin/*

Comment: I see. Did you also implement hook_menu()?

Answer (score 0):

The code used from that hook implementation is correct. It's similar to the code implemented from Drupal core, for example in [`system_admin_paths()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_admin_paths/7.x) or [`overlay_admin_paths()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21overlay%21overlay.module/function/overlay_admin_paths/7.x).

```php
function system_admin_paths() {
  $paths = array(
    'admin' => TRUE,
    'admin/*' => TRUE,
    'batch' => TRUE,
    // This page should not be treated as administrative since it outputs its
    // own content (outside of any administration theme).
    'admin/reports/status/php' => FALSE,
  );
  return $paths;
}
```

```php
function overlay_admin_paths() {
  $paths = array(
    // This is marked as an administrative path so that if it is visited from
    // within the overlay, the user will stay within the overlay while the
    // callback is being processed.
    'overlay/dismiss-message' => TRUE,
  );
  return $paths;
}
```

The explanation about the *admin-dvr/dvr/manage* path being shown sometimes with the administrative theme and sometimes with the default theme I could find is that there is a module that is setting the theme to use with [`hook_custom_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7.x).
The `hook_admin_paths()` implementations are, indirectly, invoked by [`system_custom_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_custom_theme/7.x), which is a `hook_custom_theme()` implementation.

```php
function system_custom_theme() {
  if (user_access('view the administration theme') && path_is_admin(current_path())) {
    return variable_get('admin_theme');
  }
}
```

Alternatively, basing on the code used by [`menu_get_custom_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_custom_theme/7.x) and the comment before it, a theme callback could exist for that path, and that theme callback sometimes return the name of the default theme as name of the theme to use for that path.

```php
// If there is a theme callback function for the current page, execute it.
// If this returns a valid theme, it will override any theme that was set
// by a hook_custom_theme() implementation above.
$router_item = menu_get_item();
if (!empty($router_item['access']) && !empty($router_item['theme_callback']) && function_exists($router_item['theme_callback'])) {
  $theme_name = call_user_func_array($router_item['theme_callback'], $router_item['theme_arguments']);
  if (drupal_theme_access($theme_name)) {
    $custom_theme = $theme_name;
  }
}
```